# PHP error using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using simple_html_dom to extract data from a website the code works great but it looks like it's searching for an object at the beginning. The error displays "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object" This is on the line of  **echo $e->children(0)->href . '
';**

Here is the code:

```
<?php

//$searchURL = "site";
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$site = 'http://espnfc.com/team/fixtures/_/id/359/league/eng.1/arsenal?cc=5739';
$html = file_get_html($site);


// Find all TD tags with "align=center"
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $e)
echo $e->children(0)->href . '<br>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. It will do that, if you are trying to get `href` from that `children(0)`, and that `$e` element does not have children.

```
$html = file_get_html('http://espnfc.com/team/fixtures/_/id/359/league/eng.1/arsenal?cc=5739');
foreach($html->find('td[align=center]') as $element) {
       if ($element->children(0)) { // work only when children exists
              echo $element->children(0)->href. '<br>';
       }
}
```

Look at my [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GdtIaI) for your specific case and read [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).